# join query by date

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Please someone can help me.

I need to join this two queries and grouped by hour. The query result can have many days.

RESULT: [Query1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXH34.png)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( Venta.fechaImpresion,  "%h" ) AS fechaImpresion2, COUNT( * ) AS total
FROM  `Venta` 
WHERE Venta.fechaImpresion LIKE  "2016-05-02 %"
GROUP BY HOUR( Venta.fechaImpresion ) , DAY( Venta.fechaImpresion ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

RESULT:[Query2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJSmu.png)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Venta.fechaImpresion,"%h") as fechaImpresion FROM `Venta`
where Venta.fechaImpresion >= "2016-05-02" and Venta.fechaImpresion <= "2016-05-09"  
 GROUP BY hour( Venta.fechaImpresion)
```

If i try to joined in one query the result are zero.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( Venta.fechaImpresion,  "%h" ) AS fecha, dia1.total AS total1
FROM  `Venta` 
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( Venta.fechaImpresion,  "%h" ) AS fechaImpresion
FROM  `Venta` 
WHERE Venta.fechaImpresion >=  "2016-05-02"
AND Venta.fechaImpresion <=  "2016-05-09"
GROUP BY HOUR( Venta.fechaImpresion )
)fecha ON fecha.fechaImpresion = Venta.fechaImpresion
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( Venta.fechaImpresion,  "%h" ) AS fechaImpresion2, COUNT( * ) AS total
FROM  `Venta` 
WHERE Venta.fechaImpresion LIKE  "2016-05-02 %"
GROUP BY HOUR( Venta.fechaImpresion ) , DAY( Venta.fechaImpresion )
)dia1 ON ( dia1.fechaImpresion2 = fecha.fechaImpresion ) 
WHERE Venta.fechaImpresion >=  "2016-05-02"
AND Venta.fechaImpresion <=  "2016-05-09"
GROUP BY HOUR( Venta.fechaImpresion )
```

Comment: You want to join on hour even if they are from different days?

Comment: no, from the same day

Comment: You may want to look into using `EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM fechaImpresion)` for your JOINs, et al.

Comment: @Nicarus Thanks so much !! EXTRACT is workig. Regards

Comment: Glad you got it working. Maybe you could post your solution and accept it for others reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

Select b.second table column, a.* from a first table, b second table where a.date column = b.date column

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using two separate handles for the tables.  Something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( v1.fechaImpresion,  "%h" ) AS fechaImpresion2, COUNT( v1.* ) AS total, DATE_FORMAT(v2.fechaImpresion,"%h") as fechaImpresion
FROM  `Venta` v1, 'Venta' v2 where v1.fechaImpresion = v2.fechaImpresion
```

You could then apply the various date criteria as you would like.